# Mounting an ISO with sys/mount.h

Tags: c++, linux, system, mount

I'm trying to mount an ISO file in a C++ program in linux

I'm aware of the linux command to achieve this, i.e mount -o loop ~/Test.iso /mnt/myISO

But the mount(2) man page states the following prototype for mounting :

```
int mount(const char *source, const char *target,
const char *filesystemtype, unsigned long mountflags,
const void *data);
```

How do I specify the loop option here ?

--

Also, is it good (/acceptable) practice in general, in linux programming to use system shell calls from C++ to achieve tasks such as these ?

Comment: In some cases a script is better but it really depends on what your goal is.

Comment: The loop options get passed to `losetup` if memory serves.

Comment: @JesusRamos In the latter part of my question, I mean to ask, is it a good/acceptable practice to use the c++ system() function to call the relavant linux commands (not creating shell scripts).. In this case I'm creating a GUI for mounting ISOs.

Comment: @flak37 In some cases yes, as long as user input is properly handled so that you don't get injection attacks i.e someone escaping the mount command and doing "mount -o loop /dev/fake; rm -rf /" or something of the sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

small example

```
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <linux/loop.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int file_fd, device_fd;

    file_fd = open("./TVM_TOMI1.iso", O_RDWR);
    if (file_fd < -1) {
        perror("open backing file failed");
        return 1;
    }
    device_fd = open("/dev/loop0", O_RDWR);
    if (device_fd < -1) {
        perror("open loop device failed");
        close(file_fd);
        return 1;
    }
    if (ioctl(device_fd, LOOP_SET_FD, file_fd) < 0) {
        perror("ioctl LOOP_SET_FD failed");
        close(file_fd);
        close(device_fd);
        return 1;
    }
    close(file_fd);
    close(device_fd);
    mount("/dev/loop0","/mnt/iso","iso9660",MS_RDONLY,"");
}
```

upd:
after unmount you need free loop:

```
device_fd = open("/dev/loop0", O_RDWR);
...
if (ioctl(device_fd, LOOP_CLR_FD, 0) < 0) {
    perror("ioctl LOOP_CLR_FD failed");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That explained the process, just what I needed. Another thing, how can I find out if a .iso file has the iso9660 format or the UDF format ?

Comment: @flak37 try "auto", or check format by offset or use libmagic. http://wiki.it46.se/doku.php/myhacks/tunning_asterisknow_cd

Comment: one question about  freeing loop. If program does not control unmount. I.e it was closed and mounted iso stay in system. Will system free loop when user manualy unmounts(i.e with bash command) it?

Comment: Be aware that loop0 could be busy or even do not exist. You should look for available loop devices before attach and mount.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code, that also creates loop device for you. Be aware not to use such code in production, as there is no single check on return values, exceptions etc :).

```
#include <sys/mount.h>  //mount
#include <sys/ioctl.h>  //ioctl
#include <sys/stat.h>   //open
#include <linux/loop.h> //LOOP_SET_FD
#include <fcntl.h>      //open
#include <cstdio>       // declaration of ::fileno
#include <cstdint>      //int32_t
#include <sstream>      //std::stringstream
#include <string>

constexpr char IMAGE_NAME[] = "image.iso";       //of course we need this file to be present in same folder as built tool
constexpr char MOUNT_POINT[] = "/tmp/image_mnt"; //of course we need this folder already created
constexpr char FILESYSTEM_TYPE[] = "iso9660";
constexpr char DEV_LOOP_CONTROL[] = "/dev/loop-control";
constexpr char DEV_LOOP_PREFIX[] = "/dev/loop";
constexpr int32_t MOUNT_FLAGS = MS_RDONLY;

int main()
{
    const auto loop_control = std::fopen(DEV_LOOP_CONTROL, "r");
    const auto loop_control_fd = fileno(loop_control);
    const auto devnr = ioctl(loop_control_fd, LOOP_CTL_GET_FREE);
    std::stringstream loopname;
    loopname << DEV_LOOP_PREFIX << devnr;
    const auto loop_device_name = loopname.str();
    const auto loop_device = std::fopen(loop_device_name.c_str(), "r");
    const auto loop_device_fd = fileno(loop_device);
    const auto image = std::fopen(IMAGE_NAME, "r");
    const auto image_fd = fileno(image);
    //Associate the loop device with the open file whose file descriptor is passed as the (third) ioctl(2) argument.
    ioctl(loop_device_fd, LOOP_SET_FD, image_fd);
    const auto result = mount(loop_device_name.c_str(), MOUNT_POINT, FILESYSTEM_TYPE, MOUNT_FLAGS, NULL);
    ioctl(loop_device_fd, LOOP_CLR_FD, 0);
    return result;
}
```

based on:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/loop.4.html
https://linux.die.net/man/2/mount